# configure nginx as a webserver with puma for application without domain

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy, puma, proxypass

I have a cloud server and my application is on my server. I currently do not have a domain but i would like to use nginx as a webserver for my application. So i configured in the nginx the following for this application.

I do not have a domain so `example.com` is just used as a proxy_pass url but it doesnt seem to be working.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com

```
    upstream puma_example {
      server unix:///home/deploy/sites/example.com/shared/tmp/sockets/example.sock;
    }

    server {
      listen 80 ;
      server_name example.com;

      gzip on;
      gzip_http_version 1.0;
      gzip_disable "msie6";
      gzip_vary on;
      gzip_min_length 1100;
      gzip_buffers 64 8k;
      gzip_comp_level 3;
      gzip_proxied any;
      gzip_types text/css text/xml application/x-javascript application/atom+xml text/mathml text/plain text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor text/vnd.wap.wml text/x-component;

      root /home/deploy/sites/example.com/current/public;
      access_log /home/deploy/sites/example.com/current/log/nginx.access.log;
      error_log /home/deploy/sites/example.com/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

      location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
      }

      try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma_example;
      location @puma_example {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass http://puma_example;
      }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 25M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

When i run my rails application i can see that is running but i cant seem to link it via nginx. So when i so `http://example.com`, it doesnt load my application.

What am i missing? how do i get my application to connect locally via nginx with no domain name on my cloud server.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your ip address, here is a simplified example.

```
upstream 127.0.0.1 {
   server unix:///var/run/yourapp.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  root /var/www/yourapp/current/public;

 location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/; 
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```